# Scrolling the Raspberry Pi 400 console

Tags: linux, keyboard, pi-400

In console mode (without any GUI running), the usual key combination for scrolling is Shift+Page Up/Down. However, on the Raspberry Pi 400, this combination, which should map to Shift+Fn+Up/Down, doesn't work.

Is this key combination somehow remapped in the RPi400? If so, to what?

Comment: Incidentally, there doesn't seem to be a tag for the pi-400...

Comment: There is one now.

Comment: Have you tried screen or thux?

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes, but I think the initial question is still relevant. Shouldn't have to use additional software to get basic functionality I've had on the linux console since my 486 times ;-)